# Custom tags applied to Azure web app pages in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

**Use case**: Categorizing page views in an Azure web app for analytics reporting

Using Azure Application Insights, I can see a list of pages in an Azure web app and its number of views in the past X days.

The web app is a documentation website. I would like to categorize each page with a tag like `install-info` or `api-doc` or `intro-material`, etc. The goal is that I can easily see information like "X number of page views were around install information" or "API pages received 25% of traffic," etc.

Currently I am exporting a table of each page and its number of views. Then I manually categorize each page in Excel. There are hundreds of pages. I would love to export a table that included a third column showing the page's custom tag.

Looking at Microsoft documentation, it sounds like this is possible with custom coding and the API, but I would like a simpler strategy if one exists, as I am not a sophisticated coder.

If there are alternative methods of achieving my goal than the solution I'm asking about in this question, I would be grateful to know.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using kusto to export the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add an extra tag(column) for different kind of url, right?

If that's the case, you can take use of [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) and [extend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extendoperator) statement of kusto.

Here is an sample code:

```
pageViews 
| where name contains "WebApplication5"
| extend mytags = case(
    //here, I'm using name for each condition, you can use other field as per your need.
    name=="Home Page - WebApplication5","index page",
    name=="Privacy Policy - WebApplication5","privacy page",
    "others"
)
| project name,mytags
```

Then export the result. The test result is as below:

[image]

Please feel free to modify this code to meet your requirement, and also let me know if you still have more issues about that.

Comment: Your recommendation solved my use case completely. I genuinely appreciate your Kusto query and example.